# Spring AOP Transaction - Property Based Timeout?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Can I use Spring EL to essentially pull the timeout value from a property file and convert it to an integer when dealing with Spring Transactions/AOP?

Here is the code

```
<tx:advice id="GlobalDataTxAdvice" transaction-manager="GlobalDataTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
        <tx:method name="search*" read-only="true" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
        <tx:method name="*" timeout="${service.jta.timeout:60}"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

So I want the default transaction timeout to be 60 seconds, or allow the timeout (int value) to be pulled from a property placeholder file.

But when I deploy this I get:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${service.jta.timeout:60}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<util:properties id="contextProperties" location="classpath:context.properties"/>

<tx:advice id="GlobalDataTxAdvice" transaction-manager="GlobalDataTransactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="get*" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
    <tx:method name="find*" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
    <tx:method name="search*" read-only="true" no-rollback-for="javax.persistence.NoResultException,javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException,org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/>
    <tx:method name="*" timeout="#{ T(Integer).valueOf(contextProperties['timeout']?: 60)}"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

[MoreInfo:link](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/essential/core/1.0.1/reference/html/ch05.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  On deploy I get the same type of error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '#{ T(Integer).valueOf(contextProperties['timeout']?: 60)}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.

Comment: If I read the exception over again, looks like this happens because during deploying the parsing of the Spring Context file must use validation against the Spring TX Schema, and the timeout attribute is defined as xs:integer and cannot be anything non-numeric.

Comment: Are you using Spring 3.0+ because SpEL was introduced in 3 and you should get something like SpelParseException